# Alter form in My Account Page of Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I added the Two Fields newly one is `Name` and `Mobile`.

When I am using the alter in this

```
$form['field_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

it works, when I want to change the title, type, likewise and button to change the name with OTP of Mobile Number its not working

```
$form['field_name']['#title'] = t('member name');
```

[My account image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tP6J.png)

Comment: update your question with complete form array.

Comment: I used to add field in (people > configuration > Account settings > Manage fields) Name and Mobile Number. Where i want add the default value and make it as the in-editable.  If i want to Edit, i have to use the OTP to update it. Before that e-mail Id to be masked view.(ganga@xxxx.com)

Comment: where have you written this line "$form['field_name']['#title'] = t('member name');"

Comment: function ppcp_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {    $form['field_name']['#title'] = t('member name');                  $form['field_name']['#access'] = FALSE;     }                                                   Actually ['#access'] it works but title is not change.

Comment: have you cleared your cache after changing the form array, may be it got cached.

Comment: I cleared the cache the (Access-> True or False works) but for the title name and mobile number extra field i add is not working.

Comment: ($form['field_name']['#title'] = t('member name'); ) -> it not works       $form['field_name']['#access'] = FALSE; -> it works                                  The E-mail (  $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = t('Login ID');  ) ->  its works.

Comment: before $form['field_name']['#title'] = t('member name'); and after $form['field_name']['#title'] = t('member name'); can you check what array are you getting. I mean what is the machine name of the field by using print_r function

Comment: (Machine name -> field_name -> Name) (Machine name -> field_mobile_number -> Mobile No)

Comment: check your system table and make your custom module execute at last by increasing your module weight.

Comment: $form['account']['mail']['#attributes'] = array('readonly' => 'readonly'); // (working)
    $form['field_first_name']['#default_value'] = $val_request->custName; // (not working)
    $form['field_first_name']['#weight'] = 500; // (working)
    $form['field_customer_id']['#attributes'] = array('readonly' => 'readonly'); // (not working)
    $form['field_gender']['#access'] = FALSE; // (working) .created custom fields in(configuration > people > account settings > manage fields ) but like to array fields to alter ( i used dpm($form) not able to find it)

Comment: may be the "not working" attributes are being overwritten by some other contrib / custom modules. You can do it via inspecting the form array at different places like before your changes, after your changes, template.php file and lastly at the tpl file where the form is rendered. For dpm function you must give permission to anonymous user to view developer information.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution for this

```
$form['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#value'] = 'XXXXX';
$form['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#attributes'] = array('readonly' => 'readonly');
```

Try this. Suggest me Ok.